# Images in a horizontal recyclerview switces around

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a simple horizontal recyclerview with images and some text etc.
But for some reason, the images are switcing around and ending up in the wrong places when I scroll back and forth.

The problem lies, without a doubt in the adapter:

```
public class SponsoredAdvertsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SponsoredAdvertsAdapter.SponsoredAdvertHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<CustomAdvert> adverts;
    private boolean isBigScreen;

    public SponsoredAdvertsAdapter(Context context, List<CustomAdvert> adverts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.adverts = adverts;
        isBigScreen = ScreenUtil.isBigScreen(context);
    }

    @Override
    public SponsoredAdvertsAdapter.SponsoredAdvertHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_search_popular_adverts_phone, null);
        if (isBigScreen) {
            layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_search_popular_adverts_tablet, null);
        }
        return new SponsoredAdvertHolder(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SponsoredAdvertHolder holder, int position) {

        final CustomAdvert advert   = adverts.get(position);
        String title                = advert.getAdvert().getValidTextShort();

        holder.title.setText(title);
        holder.unreadBadge.setText(context.getString(R.string.customer_tilbudsaviser_unread_advert));
        if (advert.isRead()) {
            holder.unreadBadge.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.unreadBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (holder.image != null) {
            attachAdvertImage(holder.image, holder.imageView);
        } else {
            String logoUrl = ImageScaleUrlBuilder.getFixedWidthUrl(advert.getLogoUrl(), holder.imageView.getMeasuredWidth());
            ImageLoaderHelper.loadImageFromUrl(logoUrl, new ImageLoaderHelper.ImageLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    holder.image = bitmap;
                    attachAdvertImage(bitmap, holder.imageView);
                }
            });
        }

        AdvertActivity.startAdvertActivity(context, advert.getCustomer(), advert.getAdvert(), 0, null);
    }

    private void attachAdvertImage(final Bitmap image, final ImageView imageView) {
        RunOnUIThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adverts.size();
    }

    public class SponsoredAdvertHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final View container;
        private final ImageView imageView;
        private final TextView title, unreadBadge;
        private Bitmap image;


        public SponsoredAdvertHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            container   = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_search_popular_adverts_container);
            imageView   = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_popular_advert_imageview);
            title       = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_popular_advert_title);
            unreadBadge = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread_badge);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I set the adapter to the recyclerview:

```
sponsoredAdvertsAdapter = new SponsoredAdvertsAdapter(getContext(), adverts);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        sponsoredAdvertsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        sponsoredAdvertsRecyclerView.setAdapter(sponsoredAdvertsAdapter);
```

And here is the recyclerview (xml):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/popular_searches_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/popular_adverts_searches_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the xml for the item:¨

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_search_popular_adverts_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_popular_advert_imageview"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_popular_advert_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_grey"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/unread_badge"
        layout="@layout/item_badge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/customer_tilbudsaviser_unread_advert"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that this is a fairly common problem with Recyclerviews, but even after looking at other solutions, I can't seem to get my solution to work.

Comment: Did you try to change the width and height of the item from `match_parent` to `wrap_parent`?

Comment: @HoangNguyen Yes I just tried that.. no difference. But I don't know why that would solve the problem. Any particular reason why you are suggesting this?

Comment: Ah, My bad, sorry. I misunderstand your issue.

Comment: Okay.. no worries

Comment: Maybe your issue here `if (holder.image != null){attachAdvertImage(holder.image, holder.imageView);}` holder hold your views so they  don't need to recreate but it doesn't hold your image. So it will run ok first time but when you scroll it will be shown in the wrong position.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is `holder.image` for cache image? But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Im suggesting you to use an image library like Glide ([git link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)) to display with image view. it will cache the images properly and show. this may fix the issue ;)

use glide by replacing this line

> imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

to

```
Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(bitmap)
    .centerCrop()
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```